# how to popup a modal dialog box that use window.open in jquery after click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in learning jQuery and Javascript. I want a window modal dialog pop up when click a button.Also I must use window.open in the function as it is easier for me.Before this I use showModalDialog but since it is deprecated and cannot run on Chrome, I tried to use jQuery UI. This is what I managed so far:

```
   $('#openDialog4').click(function (event) {           

    event.preventDefault();

    var url = "http://www.typescriptlang.org/";
    var windowName = "popUp";
    var windowSize = "width=200,height=200";

    result = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);    
});

<input type="button" id="openDialog4" value="Open Dialog window" />
```

It popup a window dialog when I click the button but it is not modal. Thank you.

Comment: Well `window.open` is one thing and modal is another. Modal suggests a blocking interface which must be dealt with before you can get back to the page behind it. That will never be the case with `window.open`, which merely opens a new tab in the stack. There are plenty of modal plugins out there you can use e.g. Facebook, jQuery UI Modal etc.

Comment: Hi @Utkanos. Thanks for the information. So you are saying that I cant open a window using window.open in a jQuery modal dialog box? Do u have any other way or ideas to create a modal dialog box ( that contain url ) to pop up after clicking button ?

Comment: An opened window and a modal popup are different things. There used to be native modals; these are deprecated, but live on in the form of the native `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm`. These days modals are simulated using HTML and JavaScript. The answer below discusses the Twitter Bootstrap modal, for example. Facebook has another one. You don't feed URLs to modals normally; do you mean you want a URL to open in a pop-up frame on top of the parent page?

Comment: @Utkanos yes .. and i want it to be in a modal dialog. I found other way. Let say I want to change the URL to a form. So when I click a button a form pop up in modal dialog. But, on clicking the button, there are some function for validation check that I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap modal :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Bhavin. Thanks for the respond. Is there any other way than bootstrap that I can use? Because I have not learn about it yet. But surely I will give it a try.